# Chance of randomly guessing 21 questions right out of 50 with 4 multiple choice.

Tags: probability, statistics

Lets say a person decided to randomly fill in a scantron of 50 questions with 4 choices each. After submitting it to be graded, the result was 42% correct. How would we figure out the probability of this occurring completely by chance?

This problem actually came up while I was watching a show. I would assume that a probability test is to be used here. Observed is 21, while the expected is 12.5 questions. How would one go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each the answer to each question is independently chosen, the answer should be the number of ways we can order 21 correct answers and 29 incorrect answers.

A correct answer has a probability of $1/4$ for an individual question, and $3/4$ for an incorrect answer.

There are ${50 \choose 21}$ ways to select the 21 correct answers out of 50 questions.  So the final probability should be 
$$
{50 \choose 21} (1/4)^{21}(3/4)^{29}
$$
This works out to about 0.3%

Comment: Oooh yes, that seems right. I guess I should have clarified in my question that I wanted to figure out the probability of getting 42% or better, which would just be the summation of your formula from 21 to 50.

Any idea on if there is a more clean way of writing and calculating that though?

Comment: @SeitokaiShino: as an approximation, adding another correct reduces the probability by about a factor $3$ as the combinatoric factor doesn't change much.  The sum of $1+\frac 13+\frac 1{3^2}+\dots=\frac 32$, so the total will be about $\frac 32$ times the value above.